# jQuery reusable functions and global vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a function which also set a few global variables. The function itself works fine but whenever I call the function a second time the global variables get changed obviously.

Here's my theoretical setup:

```
var dataurl;
var datafunction;

function GetData(_url, _function)
{
  dataurl = _url;
  datafunction = _function;
}

//Afterwards dataurl and datafunction will used by other functions.
```

Now I'm very new to jquery and I'm not sure on how to create this in a proper way so it can be reused more then 1 time. Could someone please help me in the right direction?

Comment: We really need to see more code than that.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? This isn't really jQuery either, it's just javascript.

Comment: I've been told many times that global vars are bad.

Comment: I'm very new to (proper) jquery so it was more a theoritical question which I couldnt find out with tutorials. Thanks

Comment: If this was Jeopardy, I'd reply with: "What is OOP, Alex?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create objects:

```
var myObject = function() {
    // Local variable
    this.data = '';

    // Function to call
    this.callMe = function() {
        alert(this.data);
    }

    // Function to set data
    this.setData = function(newData) {
        this.data = newData;
    }
}

var a = new myObject();
a.setData('Hello World!');
a.callMe();
```

Comment: And then you can create lots of objects with their own variables.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this relates to an element (jQuery plugin), but here is how you can structure your prototype:

```
var DataHelper = function(_url, _function){
    this.dataurl = _url;
    this.datafunction = _function;
};
DataHelper.prototype = {
    GetData: function(){
        // loads data from storage
        // using this.dataurl, and this.datafunction
    }
};
```

**Usage:**

```
var dataHelper = new DataHelper('/mysite/url/', function(){
    // data function
}); 

dataHelper.GetData();
```